# Set names in self-join model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, nested-attributes

I'm using AwesomeNestedSet gem for populate tree of categories.

Model:

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
 attr_accessible :name, parent_id
 has_many :subcategories, :class_name => "Category", :foreign_key => "parent_id"
 belongs_to :parent_category, :class_name => "Category"
 acts_as_nested_set
end
```

And I needed output collection of names like this:

```
Category_1
Category_1 >> Category_2
Category_1 >> Category_2 >> Category_3
Category_4
```

What the best method to do it with minimal count queries for DB?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, for answer on own question....

Simple:

```
def self.nested_names
    name = ""
    Category.each_with_level(Category.all) do |category, level|
      if category.root?
        name = category.name
      else
        name += " >> " + category.name
      end
      category.name = name
    end
  end
```